# Aws Kendra and Spring boot

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-kendra

I want to integrate spring boot with the aws kendra query index.I want to leverage kendra as elastic search where i make api for search query and then get results for the same via that api.

Documentations dont clearly mention the connection procedure/steps. Not sure if thats possible or not.

P.s created index and dataSource as webcrawler. Now whats the step forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can follow the official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/searching-example.html) to query an index. The tricky part is to provide the credentials while building the `KendraClient` object. The code is taken mostly from the link mentioned with the addition of creating Kendra Client.

A sample code would look like as below -

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.KendraClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.QueryRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.QueryResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.QueryResultItem;

public class SearchKendraIndex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String accessKey = "your-access-key";
        String secretKey = "your-secret-key";

        AwsCredentials awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);

        KendraClient kendra = KendraClient
                .builder()
                .region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1) // Change it with your region
                .credentialsProvider(() -> awsCredentials)
                .build();

        String query = "your-search-term";
        String indexId = "your-index-id";

        QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest
                .builder()
                .queryText(query)
                .indexId(indexId)
                .build();

        QueryResponse queryResponse = kendra.query(queryRequest);

        System.out.printf("\nSearch results for query: %s%n", query);
        for (QueryResultItem item : queryResponse.resultItems()) {
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.printf("Type: %s%n", item.type());
            switch (item.type()) {
                case QUESTION_ANSWER, ANSWER -> {
                    String answerText = item.documentExcerpt().text();
                    System.out.println(answerText);
                }
                case DOCUMENT -> {
                    String documentTitle = item.documentTitle().text();
                    System.out.printf("Title: %s%n", documentTitle);
                    String documentExcerpt = item.documentExcerpt().text();
                    System.out.printf("Excerpt: %s%n", documentExcerpt);
                }
                default -> System.out.printf("Unknown query result type: %s%n", item.type());
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------------\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of how to INVOKE AWS Services from a Spring BOOT app. Here are a few that show use of the **AWS SDK for Java V2**:

1. [Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)
2. [Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app).
3. [Creating the Amazon DynamoDB web application item tracker](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app)

There are more Spring BOOT/AWS Service examples in [Github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases).

While there are no Spring BOOT examples for Kendra client (yet), the pattern is the same. You can build a MVC app and build a service that uses https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/kendra/KendraClient.html.

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.KendraClient;

private KendraClient kendraClient = KendraClient.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1) <-- can be any region -->
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("<accesskeyID>", "<secretAccerssKey>")))
                .httpClientBuilder(ApacheHttpClient.builder()
                        .proxyConfiguration(ProxyConfiguration.builder()
                                .endpoint(URI.create("<proxy url if any>"))
                                .build()))
                .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) to make API calls to AWS services. You can find code examples in the link above.

Setting up your Kendra client will look something like this:

```
String accessKey = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY";
String secretKey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY";
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AWSkendra kendraClient = AWSkendraClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .build();
```

After you set up your Kendra client, you can then use the [query method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kendra/AWSkendra.html#query-com.amazonaws.services.kendra.model.QueryRequest-) to query your Kendra index.

Comment: Should always use V2 over V1.... https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/kendra/KendraClient.html